# Comparison of principal diagonals of two positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector

Let us consider a matrix with positive elements: ${\bf X}^{k\times2}=[X_1:\ldots:X_k]'$ with $X_i=(1,X_{1i})',\;i=1,\ldots,k$. Also consider ${\bf X}^{(-1)}$ as the Moore-Penrose inverse of ${\bf X}$ and the projection matrix $P_X={\bf X}{\bf X}^{(-1)}$.

Let us consider three $k\times k$ diagonal matrices with positive elements and denoted as $D_1,D_2$ and $D_3$.

Then is it always true that: $$[{\bf X}'D_1P_XD_2P'_XD_3{\bf X}]_{[1,1]}\geq[{\bf X}'D_1D_2D_3{\bf X}]_{[1,1]},$$ and 
$$[{\bf X}'D_1P_XD_2P'_XD_3{\bf X}]_{[2,2]}\geq[{\bf X}'D_1D_2D_3{\bf X}]_{[2,2]},$$
where $M_{[1,1]}$ is the $[1,1]$ elements of $M$.

Comment: there are counterexamples even for k=3. e.g. X=[1 2;;1 1;1 1], D1=D3=diag (10,1,1) and D2=I_3